# Why does flutterfire have its own config?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

On an iOS Flutter app with Flutterfire, there are two different Firebase config files: `firebase_app_id_file.json` and the standard `GoogleService-Info.plist`.

What is the difference between them? Are they both required? I’d rather have a single source of truth. `firebase_app_id_file.json` can’t be generated in the Firebase console.

Answer (score 10):

FlutterFire maintainer here.

`firebase_app_id_file.json` file is specifically used for uploading Crashlytics debug symbols for iOS Flutter apps. It is passed as an argument to the `upload-symbols` script found in the `FirebaseCrashlytics` pod. It is still necessary with the latest, stable version of FlutterFire CLI.

However, one of the aims of the FlutterFire CLI with the latest dev release, is to remove this file from the project workspace. This is just one change that is part of the wider aim which is support for multiple environment configuration (e.g. Debug, Staging, Production).

The latest dev release places the `firebase_app_id_file.json` file in the hidden `/.dart_tools` directory found on each Flutter project. The FlutterFire CLI dev release also tracks multiple `firebase_app_id_file.json` files for each build environment configured by the user in this hidden directory.

At this moment in time, I wouldn't recommend users rely on Dart initialisation for their apps. Certain Firebase products (e.g. Analytics, FCM & Performance monitoring) on native platforms need the service file to be present to function properly at build time or when Dart side is not yet available (e.g. background message initialisation).

The `firebase_options.dart` file is still written as part of the FlutterFire CLI as it is useful for initialising web applications.

You will note that the `GoogleService-Info.plist` is still written when running `flutterfire configure` on the latest, stable version of FlutterFire CLI. This is bundled with your app at build time and used by Firebase to initialise your app.

Comment: Thanks for this. But why is `firebase_app_id_file.json` required for `upload-symbols`? Why can't symbol uploading be done in the usual way for Firebase on iOS? It seems like the same information is provided in `GoogleService-Info.plist`

Comment: Also when you say `We don’t recommend users rely on Dart initialisation for their apps.`. Does this mean you recommend initialising Firebase in the usual native way for each platform?